# c# Unity - Referencing a static variable in EditorWindow returns a null reference

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have `cRound` class that stores a static variable of `cRound[]` that list out the data for the rounds in my game. I'm trying to make an inspector to display the information stored in that array but the window gives me a null reference exception when the game is not running. It works fine when the game does run.

Is there a way to initialize this variable without running the game?

```
public void OnGUI()
    {
        if (cRound.rounds == null) // cause cRound to return an exception
            return;

        for (int i = 0; i < cRound.rounds.Length; i++)
        {
            PackRound(cRound.rounds[i], i);
        }
        
    }
```

Here's the static variable in the `cRound` class

```
public class cRound
{
    // Other stuff

    public static cRound[] rounds = new cRound[]
    {
       // Array of cRound's...
    };

    //More stuff
}
```

Comment: @MickyD the field `rounds` is **static** so it doesn't belong to any instance of `cRound` .. so what would a singleton be good for here if there clearly are going to be more then one instance of `cRounds` ...? ;)

Comment: Could you post your actual code? How are you filling that array?

Comment: What's the point of `rounds`?  I can't help but think you have changed the variable names being used too.

Comment: _"Is there a way to initialize this variable without running the game?"_ - You really want to avoid having code that goes off willy-nilly **Editor**-time.  A better approach is to create a custom `Editor` and in your `OnInspectorGUI` if it is found that something is `null`, do something like `if (GUILayout.Button("Init")) { script.DoMyFunkyInit(); }`

Comment: There is more than one instance of `cRound` but only one instance of `rounds` which is just a fixed array of `cRound`s. The array is being filled when I define it. `rounds` will let the game know how many enemies to spawn, how fast, what attributes they have, and bonus money for completing the round.